# How to increment a variable of type String.CharacterView.Index?

Tags: swift, swift3

I was trying this (at the Playground):

```
class SomeClass {

    private let input: String.CharacterView
    private var position: String.CharacterView.Index

    ...

    private func advance() {

        position += 1

    } // advance

} // SomeClass
```

...but I'm getting the following error message:

> error: binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'String.CharacterView.Index' and 'Int'

The reason behind me trying to increment this index it's because I would like to do something like:

```
input[position]
```

...and access a specific character at **input**.

At this point I already know that I can't use this binary operator over **position**. What would be a viable solution?

I'm using Swift 3 and Xcode Version 8.0 beta 6 (8S201h)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift 3, "Collections move their index", compare
 [A New Model for Collections and Indices](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md) on Swift evolution.

In your case

```
private func advance() {
    input.formIndex(&position, offsetBy: 1)
}
```

would advance the index position by one. Here you have to ensure
that the index is not already equal to `endIndex`, alternatively use

```
private func advance() {
    input.formIndex(&position, offsetBy: 1, limitedBy: input.endIndex)
}
```